# Pass Powershell switch to an Azure Resource Manager Template (ARM)

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

How can I directly pass a powershell switch (System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter) to an ARM template (which will be used as a condition in the template itself)?

Currently I am using the workaround of converting the switch to an string.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say your switch is called fullversion:

```
param(
...
[switch]$fullversion
)
```

and your parameterfile also contains a parameter called fullversion then you can pass it like:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -fullversion $fullversion.IsPresent
```

Comment: and IsPresent should be mapped to boolen, I presume

Comment: Yes, IsPresent will return either false or true

Comment: well, I posted another linked question because this topic is well documented at all ... Perhaps you have a good solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718906/using-bool-parameter-type-for-conditions-in-azure-resource-manager-arm-templat