# Using bool parameter type for conditions in Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

In an ARM Template with a following parameter:

```
{
  "$schema": "...",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {

  ...

    "SkipThisComponent": {
      "type": "bool"

   ...
}
```

how would one use it inside a resource condition?

```
"resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "...",
      "name": "...",
      "type": "...",
      "condition": "[???]",
```

I tried out several approaches, but it seems that `equals` supports only [int, string, array, or object], `if` needs both the condition and values to match it to etc. I didn't find a nice clean approach, all seem to be workarounds with casting...

Comment: Kind of related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50716482/pass-powershell-switch-to-an-azure-resource-manager-template-arm

Comment: doesn't `"condition" : "[variables('SkipThisComponent')"` work?

Comment: somehow I am having a slow day today. Of course that works :) What I used in the end is `"condition": "[not(parameters('SkipThisComponent'))]"`, but it is the same think. Please post the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Glad to help you! Posted the answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can just use the variable within the condition:

```
"condition" : "[not(variables('SkipThisComponent'))]"
```

```
"condition" : "[variables('CreateThisComponent')]"
```

[Logic Functions Ref.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-logical)